# Implementing Draco 3D data Compression in Angular 7 to compress .STL files?

Tags: angular, npm, stl, drc

Is there any possible way to implement Draco 3D compression in Angular 7?
 or suggest me with some examples.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following files to be installed in your Angular Project.

```
> npm install three-full
> npm install three-orbit-control
```

three-full have the draco decoder and encoder file.

have to give the draco encoder path in the following line
Example: `THREE.DRACOLoader.setDecoderPath('./assets/draco/');
THREE.DRACOLoader.setDecoderConfig({ type: 'JS' });`

followed by render coding

> It will call draco_wasm_wrapper.js

so it will load your .drc (stl draco encode) file in your app.